# Creating Soap Fields for QueryDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

I am creating a QueryDefintionObject that extends the ETObject in the Java FuelSDK. I have been able to successfully create the following fields:

```
@InternalSoapField(name = "name")
protected String name = null;
@InternalSoapField(name="customerKey")
protected String customerKey = null;
@InternalSoapField(name="createdDate")
protected Date createdDate = null;
@InternalSoapField(name="modifiedDate")
protected Date modifiedDate = null;
@InternalSoapField(name="client")
protected ETClientID clientId = null;
@InternalSoapField(name="queryText")
protected String query = null;
```

However, I can't seem to be able to create fields for TargetType or TargetUpdateType. I was running into issues with QueryText until I realized that the documentation is UpperCamelCase while the Java implementation is lowerCamelCase. However, I cannot seem to get the InternalSoapField name correct for these two.

Comment: I did not have a getter for the targetType, so the PropertyUtils was not able to find a value for the property.

Comment: Did that solve it for you then?

Comment: Yep. Had a issue later where I did not register Fuel objects and their corresponding generate (WSDL) objects with the object converter. I should really write a post about adding object to the Java Fuel SDK. So many are missing.

Comment: Make sure you add that as an answer and then check it answered so we know.

Comment: Be sure to add an answer to this question. Thanks!